# Arithemetic Sequence Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic-progressions

Q: Domestic bees make their honeycomb by starting with a single hexagonal cell, then forming ring after ring of hexagonal cells around the initial cell, as shown. The numbers of cells in successive rings form an arithmetic sequence. a. Write a rule for the number of cells in the nth ring. b. What is the total number of cells in the honeycomb after the 9th ring is formed?
[image]

For making rule(formulae) for counting the number of cells in the nth ring, we would need the values for the following variables

a=?

d=?

I started counting cells from the initial ring and set a=1 and d=6 and start counting from the 1st ring and set a=7 and d=6 but I have got wrong answers both times then what is the correct way to find the values for variables to put in the following equation and would we count initial cell as a part of the ring?

An=a+(n-1)d

Comment: I believe the ring is meant to be the cells on the perimeter.  Note that the *second* diagram is labeled "one ring".  So, the first ring has $6$ cells and the second $12$.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number)

Comment: So we would start counting cells from 1st ring and leave the initial cell?

Comment: That is right.  The starting cell does not fit the arithmetic progression.  You have to remember to add it in for part b separately

Comment: ok,
Thanks for the help everyone